# How can I decrypt a token in NodeJS encrypted before with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, encryption

I have a little problem. I want do decrypt an encrypted token from PHP inside a NodeJS server to secure my requests. I know that there is JWT but actually the library I'm using doesn't support this. So I've wrote this little function in PHP that encrypts a value:

```
echo encrypt('Hello StackOverflow!');

function encrypt( $value, $secret_key = 'ABC', $secret_iv = 'DEF' ): string {
    $hashed_key = hash( 'sha256', $secret_key );
    $iv         = substr( hash( 'sha256', $secret_iv ), 0, 16 );

    return base64_encode( openssl_encrypt( $value, 'AES-256-CBC', $hashed_key, 0, $iv ) );
}
```

So when you execute this, it becomes this:

```
dEJZQXVPSFAvaXpSTG5jaGtlaFIwSHZ6OVNBTmFnNXJMbDFXcXlQWGZpRT0=
```

I'm looking now for a way to decrypt this in JS. Does anyone has an idea how I can do this?!

Comment: I would suggest using an encryption library that implements to a well-known standard and where a library implementation of that standard is available in both php and nodejs.  I don't know all the PHP functions you're using to know what exactly you've got here, but certainly there are a number of standard encryption schemes available in both PHP and node.js.

Comment: You should not roll your own iv creation algorithm. Openssl offers [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) which when combined with [`openssl_cipher_iv_length()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-cipher-iv-length.php) will generate a more secure iv.

Comment: @JohnConde Thanks for the hint! Maybe I should search a library that is available for PHP and Node to be sure that everything is fine.

Comment: Node has a very extensive, built-in [crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) library that has all the functions you need to create a matching `decrypt()` function. As pointed out, you should change your key and IV generation methods and possibly the mode of operation. But yes, it would be best to find a PHP-Node library.